# AngularJS Updating attribute in directive linking function dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that receives a string, which I would like the directive to then modify and add as an attribute's property.

HTML

```
<div directive ng-class="" otherAttribute="hello"></div>
```

JS

```
.directive('directive', function () {

return {

    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var classList = "{active: attrs.otherAttribute == 'hello'}";

            attrs.ngClass = classList;

            console.log(attrs);

        }

    }

})
```

This **does** seem to add the properties to the class property of the `attrs` object:

`console.log(attrs);`

```
$$observers: Object
$attr: Object
ngClass: "{active: attrs.otherAttribute == 'hello'}"
otherAttribute: "hello"
__proto__: Object
```

But the DOM is not updated. I've tried `$compile`, but that does not update the class attribute on the DOM either.

What am I missing? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interpolation and reference directive scope

```
 <div directive class="class1 {{classList}}" otherAttribute="hello"></div>

link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.classList = "class2";
}
```

Pay attention that in your code there  is an error, you reference an undefined `scope.classList` with an `+=` operator, resulting in `undefinedclass1 class2` literal. I suppose this might be a typo in example...

Comment: Seems like I was overthinking it. :-) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the directive element to modify a css class.

Working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/egrendon/vvnu5yLx/1/

```
app.directive('directive', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.classList += "class1 class2";
            element.addClass(scope.classList);
            console.log(attrs);
        }
    }
});
```